# How to insert custom core/template in product.info.options

Tags: magento-1.9, php

How can i insert a custom core/template between select and date type?

```
<reference name="product.info.options">

     <action method="addOptionRenderer" ><type>text</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_text</block><template>customoptions/options-type-text.phtml</template></action>

                <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>select</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_select</block><template>customoptions/options-type-select.phtml</template></action>


<-- custom core/template should be here -->

                <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>date</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_date</block><template>customoptions/options-type-date.phtml</template></action>

                <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>file</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_file</block><template>customoptions/options-type-file.phtml</template></action>

                <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>default</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_default</block><template>customoptions/options-type-default.phtml</template></action>


</reference>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the block added here cannot visible at frontend

for this you have to do one more step

first what you are doing is add block

```
<block type='core/template' name='myName' template="yourtemplatepath/templatenme.phtml"  >
```

and after that open below file
`app/design/frontend/Your Package/Your Theme/template/catalog/product/view/type/option/configurable.phtml`

and add below line

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('myName'); ?>`

Comment: is there any other way to achieve it?

Comment: No you cannot achieve directly you have to write getChildhtml in that file

Comment: If above answer help you then mark as accepted

Comment: You are always welcome  :)